# How to best learn how retrieve and parse JSON from an API?

Tags: json, api

I'm a web designer by education and I design WordPress-based websites using HTML5, CSS3 and some easy jQuery scripting. I want to learn how to handle JSON and RESTful API calls (e.g. retrieving data from Twitter's Streaming API), but don't know where to start.

Are there any Sitepoint, O'Reilly, or any other big publisher with books on this? Any superblog articles with tutorials? Any tips, suggestions? Pardon in advance for my rusty english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know HTTP, you know REST, so the [HTTP standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) (especially the [*Method Definitions* section](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9)). REST is just using HTTP as it was originally intended, with each URL representing a resource. Its philosophical background is explained in the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST), and at length in the [original paper](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~taylor/documents/2002-REST-TOIT.pdf).

Specifically for twitter's streaming API, consult their [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api/methods). You can easily test HTTP queries and what they return with [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) or a Python's [urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @phihag. My question, though, was how to best learn how to do that. Do you have any suggestions for books, articles or websites to do so? I've checked the dev documentation, but what I have in motivation and perspiration I lack in technical expertise. I really need a "beginner's guide", For Dummies-like introduction to programming with RESTful APIs using JSON/JavaScript. Any ideas?

Comment: @JoãoRamos Sorry, I'm notoriously bad when it comes to recommending tutorials - I think that standards are actually easier to read and allow me to understand the technology at hand instead of just seeing one potential usage. So the only suggestion I can contribute is learning by doing, for example with curl or urllib. Programming a REST *client* is supposed to be dead simple, that's why all the [books](http://search.oreilly.com/?q=restful&x=0&y=0) focus on the server side of things.